# Does convergence in distribution with correlation tending to 1 implies convergence in probability?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, convergence

Let be $(X_n)_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of random variables and $Z$ another random variable such that, when $n$ goes to infinity:

- $X_n$ converges to $Z$ in distribution : $X_n \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\to} Z$,
- The (Pearson's) correlation of $X_n$ and $Z$ converges to 1 (assuming these correlations are all well defined) : $\mathrm{corr}(X_n, Z) \to 1$.

Would this mean that $X_n$ converges to $Z$ in probability ? If not, do you think there might be another measure of dependence for which the statement could be true ?

Answer (score 3):

##### Convergence in probability holds under additional (weak) conditions

It is possible to establish convergence in probability here if you can first establish the moment convergence $\mathbb{E}(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(Z)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{V}(Z)$.  Additional conditions for the moment convergence require that the sequence of moments $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ and $\mathbb{V}(X_n)$ are bounded for sufficiently large $n$ (see e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552171/)).  Here it is worth noting that the antecedent limit condition $\mathbb{Corr}(X_n, Z) \rightarrow 1$ already implies that the correlation exists, so $\mathbb{E}(Z)$ and $\mathbb{V}(Z)$ are finite and the other moments are *finite* for sufficiently large $n$ so all we need to go further to get the required condition is to assume that they are also *bounded* for sufficiently large $n$.

Now, assuming you can first establish the required convergence in moments, you then have $\mathbb{E}(X_n - Z) \rightarrow 0$ as an initial property.  Moreover, since $\mathbb{Corr}(X_n, Z) \rightarrow 1$ and $\mathbb{V}(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{V}(Z)$ you also have the property:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(X_n - Z)
&= \mathbb{V}(X_n) - 2 \cdot \mathbb{Cov}(X_n, Z) + \mathbb{V}(Z) \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{V}(X_n) - 2 \cdot \mathbb{Corr}(X_n, Z) \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(X_n) \mathbb{V}(Z)} + \mathbb{V}(Z) \\[6pt]
&\rightarrow \mathbb{V}(Z) - 2 \times 1 \times \sqrt{\mathbb{V}(Z) \cdot \mathbb{V}(Z)} + \mathbb{V}(Z) \\[10pt]
&= 2 \mathbb{V}(Z) - 2 \mathbb{V}(Z) \\[12pt]
&= 0. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

These two properties establish convergence in mean-square which then implies convergence in probabilty (using [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality)).

Comment: $X_n$ converging in distribution to $Z$ doesn't imply $\mathbb{E}[X_n-Z]\to 0$ or $\mathbb{V}(X_n)\to \mathbb{V}(Z)$, though it may follow from the convergence of the correlations (I don't currently have a counterexample)

Comment: I think it's true, but it wouldn't be true if we had, say, $Z_n\stackrel{p}{\to}Z$ and $\mathrm{corr}[X_n,Z_n]\to 1$. The reason it's true is that $Z$ is fixed. To cause a problem, outliers of $X_n$ have to be more and more extreme and less and less probable as $n\to\infty$, so they can't correlate well with the fixed outliers of $Z$.

Comment: @ThomasLumley: Thanks, well spotted --- I jumped the gun a bit.  I've now edited the question to point out the additional step going from convergence in distribution to convergence in moments.  Please have a look and let me know if you think there are any remaining gaps.

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.  I still need to think about how to prove that the correlation condition establishes convergence of the moments.

Comment: I don't think that works: the moments are *finite* but that doesn't imply they are *bounded*

Comment: Yes, good point.  I've rolled back to keep the condition.

Comment: @ThomasLumley where you say finite moments don’t imply they are bounded, can you clarify? Are you saying that the moment can be finite for each $n$, but the sequence of moments may not be bounded?

Comment: Yes: it's immediate that the second moments are finite for each $n$, but you need to prove there is a uniform bound for all $n$ -- they could (in principle) increase with $n$. In fact they can't, but the proof that they can't is more involved.

Answer (score 2):

Two notes on the convergence in moments assumed for @Ben's answer

#### It's not easy.

Suppose we had instead that $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} Z$, and $Z_n\stackrel{p}{\to}Z$ and $\mathbb{Corr}[X_n, Z_n]\to 1$. Convergence in probability of $X_n$ to $Z$ need not hold in this slightly modified problem.

Take

- $U\sim U[0,1]$,
- $V\sim N(0,1)$
- $X_n\sim N(0,1)$ if $U>1/n$ and $X_n=2^n$ if $U<1/n$
- $Z_n=V$ if $U>1/n$ and $Z_n=2^n$ if $U<1/n$
- $Z=V$

with all the $N(0,1)$s independent. Then $\mathbb{Corr}[X_n, Z_n]$ exists for every $n$ and converges to 1, but $X_n$ does not converge in probability to $Z$ (it doesn't converge in probability at all).

By using the same $N(0,1)$ for all $n$ in the definition of $X_n$,  you could also arrange for $X_n$ to converge in probability to a $N(0,1)$ that was independent of $Z$

#### The result is true.

You can't do anything like the construction in part 1, because $Z$ doesn't vary  with $n$.  Heuristically, you need increasingly rare and extreme outliers in the $X_n$ and they can't stay correlated with fixed outliers in $Z$

##### Proof

Rather than working with the variance, we work with a truncated variance.  Given a finite, positive $M$, write $X^M_n$ for $X_n\{|X_n|<M\}$. We know the variance of $Z$ is finite, and there's only one of it so it's also uniformly bounded and we don't need to truncate it.

Now for any fixed $M$, the truncated  variance *is* continuous with respect to convergence in distribution, so
$$\mathbb{V}[X^M_n-Z]\to \mathbb{V}[Z^M-Z]$$
and given any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $M$ so the limit is less than $\epsilon$, by finiteness of $\mathbb{V}[Z]$.

So, given $\epsilon$, we can find $N$ and $M$ such that for $n>N$
$$\mathbb{V}[X^M_n-Z]<2\epsilon$$
and (since $X_n$ converges in distribution)
$$\mathbb{P}[X_n\neq X_n^M]<\epsilon$$

Now for any $\eta$
$$\mathbb{P}[|X_n-Z]>\eta]\leq \mathbb{P}[|X_n-X_n^M]>\eta]+ \mathbb{P}[|Z-X_n^M]>\eta]$$
The first term is bounded by $\epsilon$ and the second (via Chebyshev's inequality) by something like $2\epsilon/\eta$. So we can choose $\epsilon$ to make it small and we are (finally) done.

##### Check

Why wouldn't this proof work for the modified problem where the result is false? The very first line
$$\mathbb{V}[X^M_n-Z]\to \mathbb{V}[Z^M-Z]$$
fails, since the correlation condition is on $Z_n$ rather than $Z$. It's important to the proof that $Z$ doesn't need truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a reminiscent of the CLT? If the distribution of **$X_{n}$** converges to **Z**, this means that the probability converges to **Z** as well. After all, the probabilities are obtained from distributions. Pearson coefficient:
\begin{equation}
\rho_{X,Z}=\frac{cov(X,Z)}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Z}},
\end{equation}
but in the limit n$\rightarrow$ $\infty$: X$\rightarrow$Z, thus:
\begin{equation}
\rho_{X,Z}=\frac{cov(X,Z)}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Z}}=\frac{E[XZ]-E[X]E[Z]}{\sigma^{2}}=\frac{E[Z^{2}]-E[Z]^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}=\frac{\sigma^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}=1,
\end{equation}
where I have defined $\sigma_{X}$=$\sigma_{Z}$=$\sigma$ in the limit n$\rightarrow$ $\infty$.

Comment: Does this show convergence in probability? I don’t see it.

Comment: I'm not sure of what this shows, could you detail ? Plus I don't get why E[XZ] goes to E[Z^2] in  the limit..

Comment: You use $E(XZ) = E(Z^2)$ which is not correct. That $X_n$ converges *in distribution* to $Z$ does not mean that "X becomes Z" (even in a probabilistic sense), it only means that they ultimately have the same distribution.